# Bochs 2.6.8 compile with --enable-debugger problem on Ubuntu 16.04LTS x64

Tags: compiling

I've problems with compiling Bochs. I've tried compile bochs from svn and from sourceforge. Actually I'm trying to compile Bochs 2.6.8 on Ubuntu 16.04LTS x64.
This is how I'm trying to do this:

```
./configure --enable-debugger
```

The output is:
http://pastebin.com/WNYAQicN

Then:

```
make
```

and I get this error:
http://pastebin.com/7w1qhJy8

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bochs` ?

Comment: Have you installed build-essential `sudo apt-get install build-essential`?